# Sonarqube how can fix nullpointeexception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

how can fix this nullpointerexception on sonarcube?

[image: Sonar]

**Java Code:**

```
  GeneratedKeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        String sql = "Update users set enable=true where username=:username";
        SqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("username", u.getUsername());
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, paramSource, generatedKeyHolder);
        try {
            return generatedKeyHolder.getKey().intValue();
A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "getKey()" can return null.
        }
        catch (NullPointerException nl){
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: By checking if `generatedKeyHolder.getKey()` is `null` before converting it to `int`. And please remove that `try-catch`...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
GeneratedKeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    String sql = "Update users set enable=true where username=:username";
    SqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("username", u.getUsername());
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, paramSource, generatedKeyHolder);
    try {
        Optional<Number> key = Optional.ofNullable(generatedKeyHolder.getKey());
        if(key.isEmpty())
            return null;
        else
            key.get().intValue();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException nl){
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you really want to throw an Optional in there, replace the entire thing including the `try-catch` with `return Optional.ofNullable(generatedKeyHolder.getKey()).orElse(0);` (assuming that `getKey()` returns an `Integer`).

Comment: it works thann you

Comment: @Hulk this can return null as well, your code only returns 0 if it is null.  In order to avoid try-catch only we have an Optional feature.

Comment: @ThomsonIgnesious I chose `0` as the default value because so did the OP in the `catch` block. Returning `null` is a change in behavior compared to the code in the OP, not sure if that is desired.

Comment: @Hulk  riki clearly mentioned in the code comment itself
A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "getKey()" can return null.